# Rails, Angular. How to save like Google Keep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-keep

I'm making something with Rails and AngularJS (from Google).

Can you help me with creation of a todo app (basic app I know how to do) that save the task like Google Keep?

For example, without click? Without buttons for save?

How to do?

Comment: onkeyup-->do something

Answer (score -2):

A Todo App is the most basic of apps: TodoMVC http://todomvc.com/